# How to print an array using for loop

Tags: java

We need to print out arrays for a lab but my professor does not allow us to use `java.util.Array`s. The expected output is:

```
[1, 5, 6, 9, 10]
```

I tried using a for loop to print out these values, but it keeps printing an extra ", " at the end:

```
[1, 5, 6, 9, 10, ]
```

I have tried a few different methods but I could not figure it out:

```
public String toString() {
     
     String str = "[";
     
     for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         
         str += data[i] + ", ";
         
     } // End of for loop
     
     str += "]";
         
     return str;    
     
 } // End of method
```

Comment: `if (i == data.length -1) str += data[i]; else str += data[i] + ", ";` - Keeping this in the for loop will help??

Answer (score 1):

You can add comma conditionally as below :

```
public String toString() {
     
     String str = "[";
     
     for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         if(i == (data.length - 1)){
            str += data[i];
         } else {
            str += data[i] + ", ";
         }
         
         
     } // End of for loop
     
     str += "]";
         
    return str; 
     
 } // End of method
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code,you don't need to add "," for the last element

```java
public String toString() {
     
     String str = "[";
     
     for (int i = 0; i < data.length-1; i++) {
         
         str += data[i] + ", ";
         
     } // End of for loop
     str += data[data.length-1];// for the last element don't need to use ","

     str += "]";
         
    return str; 
     
 } // End of method
```

Answer (score 1):

Clean way to do this is to use `StringJoiner` introduced in Java 8.

```
int[] data = new int[]{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 }; 

StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(", ","[","]");

for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    sj.add(String.valueOf(data[i]));
}

System.out.println(sj.toString());

//[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use a ternary operator for writing your code as below:

```
public static String toString(String[] data) {
    String str = "[";
    
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        str += (i == (data.length -1)) ? data[i] : data[i] + ", ";  
    }
    str += "]";
    
    return str;  
}
```